# Probability of hitting 2 or more home runs

Tags: probability

Jose hits a home run in 10% of all his at-bats. He gets 10 at-bats. Determine the probability that he hits 2 or more home runs.

I guess you can solve this question by subtracting the probability of getting 0 or 1 home runs from 1. So the probability of getting 0 home runs would be (9/10)^10, and the probability of getting 1 home run would be (9/10)^9, so the final equation would be: 1-((9/10)^10 + (9/10)^9) which is around 26%. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. We can calculate the probability of hitting 0 and 1 home runs and then subtract from 1.

Here, what is the probability of hitting $k (\leq 10)$ home runs?

For hitting $k$ home runs we need $k$ at-bats. In how many ways $k$ at-bats can be chosen from 10 at-bats? It's $\dbinom{10}{k}$.

So, now what is the probability that in exactly $k$ at-bats he can score a home run? It is,

$\dbinom{10}{k}$*Pr(he hits in $k$ at-bats and can't hit in $10-k$ at-bats)

= $\dbinom{10}{k}$*Pr(he hits in $k$ at-bats)*Pr(he can't hit in $10-k$ at-bats) (As, Pr(A and B)=Pr(A)*pr(B) if A and B are independent, here all the at-bats are independent and doesn't affect each other)

$=\dbinom{10}{k} {(\frac{1}{10})}^k{(\frac{9}{10})}^{10-k}$.

So, the probability that he will score 2 or more home runs is,

$1-\dbinom{10}{0} {(\frac{1}{10})}^0{(\frac{9}{10})}^{10}-\dbinom{10}{1} {(\frac{1}{10})}^1{(\frac{9}{10})}^9\\=1-{(\frac{9}{10})}^{10}-{(\frac{9}{10})}^9$

Comment: This is correct except for the last exponent on line 5 should be (10 - k), not k.

Comment: @pwerth thanks, edited

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct. The probability of hitting $0$ home runs is indeed $(\frac{9}{10})^{10}$, but the probability of hitting $1$ home run is not ($\frac{9}{10})^{9}$ - this is the probability of hitting $0$ home runs in $9$ at bats. You need to account for the one where he does hit a home run.

Edit: this is actually correct, since in this case you have a $\frac{1}{10}$ probability for the home run, and 10 at bats for where it could happen, which will cancel, but in general this will not happen.

Alternatively, you could use a binomial table. I'm assuming you've learned about the binomial distribution. Here you have a binomial with $ n= 10, \; p = .1$. You can use a CDF table to find
P($X\leq 1$), and your answer will be $1$ minus this number.

Comment: so in order to account for the one where he does hit a home run, I can just multiply (9/10)^9 by 1/10? 1/10 would be the probability of hitting the home run in the remaining bat.

Comment: see my edit - yes, you need to multiply by $\frac{1}{10}$ but you also need to multiply by 10 since there are 10 possible at bats for where the home run could occur. However, these will cancel so your answer is actually right.